# How to inflate a custom RelativeLayout programmatically?

Tags: android

I have the following custom relative layout:

```
public class CircleView extends RelativeLayout implements OnDragListener {
    private DropCallback onDrop = null;
    private ImageButton imageButton = null;
    private int radius = -1;
    private double step = -1;
    private double angle = -1;
    private static final int CENTER_ID = 111;

    public CircleView(Context context, DropCallback onDrop, int radius, List<View> views) {
        super(context);

        this.onDrop = onDrop;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.step = (2 * Math.PI) / views.size();

        this.initView(context, views);
    }

    private void initView(Context context, List<View> views) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsView);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

        this.imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
        this.imageButton.setId(CENTER_ID);
        this.imageButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        this.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_power_on);
        this.imageButton.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
        this.imageButton.setOnDragListener(this);

        this.addView(this.imageButton);

        for(View view : views) {
            this.addView(this.placeView(view));
        }
    }

    private View placeView(View view) {
        view.measure(0, 0);
        this.imageButton.measure(0, 0);

        int x = (int)((view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2) + this.radius * Math.cos(this.angle));
        int y = (int)((view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) + this.radius * Math.sin(this.angle));

        this.angle += this.step;

        int deltaX = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int deltaY = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        int deltaImageX = this.imageButton.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int deltaImageY = this.imageButton.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        int xToDraw = ((x - deltaX) - deltaImageX);
        int yToDraw = ((y - deltaY) - deltaImageY);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.setMargins(xToDraw, 0, 0, yToDraw);

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        return this.onDrop.onDrop(view, event);
    }
}
```

I have no xml layout file for this and it worked until now. 
Today i changed the activity using this custom layout to be a `Fragment` and i now need to set the layout. Unfortunately something like the following isnt possible:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    return inflater.inflate(new CircleView(this, this, 240, this.views), container, false);
}
```

So how can i inflate my custom relative layout?

Comment: what do you need inflater.inflate() for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an instance of Circle view and add it to container :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    CircleView circleView = new CircleView(this, this, 240, this.views);
    ...
    return circleView;
}
```

Comment: If i do so i get: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.controller.activities.MenuActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: @Mulgard, should your fragment only display a circleView or a complex view with a circleView in it ? I update my answer for first case.

Answer (score 0):

You should create you xml layout, for example circle_view.xml:

```
<your_package.CircleView android:id="@+id/gcircle_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

and then:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.circle_view, container, false);
}
```

btw, you should implement constructors:

```
    public CircleView(Context context){
        super(context);

    }
    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }
```

Comment: i dont understand this. where do i set my circleview now?

Comment: @Mulgard instead of new CircleView(this, this, 240, this.views) you should using now R.layout.circle_view

Comment: But thats the point. I dont want to use it. I cant create a circular layout like that using xml layout file.

Comment: The buttons i place in my CircleView are ordered along a circle. i dont have any idea of creating a circular view using the xml layout. thats the problem. isnt there any possibility to inflate custom layouts (programmatically created custom layouts!)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the inflator like this:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Then use the inflator to inflate the needed.